# Not echo a component if inside an if statement

Tags: php

So I have the below method inside my class and one thing that I was wondering if how can I make it not echo out an component if its detected that it's null.

```
public function sync_profiles(object $record): Profile
{
    $profile = $this->get_profile($record->id);
    var_dump($profile);

    $default = [
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 0,
        'octopus_id' => $record->id,
    ];

    $update = [
        'post_title' => $record->first_name . ' ' . $record->last_name,
        'peoplesoft_id' => $record->employee_id,
        'first_name' => $record->first_name,
        'last_name' => $record->last_name,
        'email_address' => $record->email,
    ];

    if ($profile === null) {
        $profile = new Profile(array_merge($default, $update));
        echo '<pre>Profile ' . $record->id . ' has been created</pre>';
    }
    $profile->load($update);
    $profile->save();
    echo '<pre>Profile ' . $record->id . ' has been updated</pre>';

    return $profile;
}
```

So the above code code outputs the following messages:

> us.php:247:null (This is the var_dump):
>   Profile ID: 7899 has been created
>   Profile ID: 7899 has been updated

If it finds that `$profile` is null, it'll merge the data arrays and echo the message.. If `$profile` is null, echo only the created message and if it'a not null, echo only the updated message.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more precise which of both echo's should not appear? The question is not clear to me. Do you want to have just one of both messages respectively to the executed action?

Comment: @ChristophKluge, correct - I want the created message to only appear when $profile is null, and then have the updated message appear when it's doesn't pass in the if statement

Comment: else if statement or switch case? tried these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comment.

I would use an if-statement and return the profile after the update. In this case you stop the function from further execution. In this case it will not execute the creation anymore. You can also use your existing if-statement and add an else to it. It would have the same effect.

```
public function sync_profiles(object $record): Profile
{
    $update = [
        'post_title' => $record->first_name . ' ' . $record->last_name,
        'peoplesoft_id' => $record->employee_id,
        'first_name' => $record->first_name,
        'last_name' => $record->last_name,
        'email_address' => $record->email,
    ];

    $profile = $this->get_profile($record->id);
    if (!is_null($profile)) {
      $profile->load($update);
      $profile->save();

      echo '<pre>Profile ' . $record->id . ' has been updated</pre>';

      return $profile;
    }

    $profile = new Profile(array_merge([
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 0,
        'octopus_id' => $record->id,
    ], $update));
    $profile->load($update);
    $profile->save();

    echo '<pre>Profile ' . $record->id . ' has been updated</pre>';

    return $profile;
}
```

In case you want my personal opinion then I would go with 2 new methods. One for a new profile sync and another one for an updated profile sync to keep the logic separated. It could look like this:

```
public function sync_profiles(object $record): Profile 
{
    $profile = $this->get_profile($record->id);

    return is_null($profile) 
        ? $this->sync_profiles_new($record)
        : $this->sync_profiles_existing($record, $profile);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response @Christoph, this worked perfectly! I've upvoted the post, please upvote mine also :)